# Training models on EC2 with local data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tensorflow

I am working with amazon's aws EC2 instances to train my image classifier (cnn). I have a dataset of about 200k images and scp -ing it all up to the instance seems inefficient, especially as the dataset grows. Is there a way to train the models on the EC2 instance while pointing to a dataset directory on a local machine.

So for example if I am training my model locally I would use something like this to start training:

```
python retrain.py  \
    --image_dir /Users/vivek/Desktop/Data2Compress/\
   --learning_rate=0.001 \
    --testing_percentage=20 \
    --validation_percentage=20 \
    --train_batch_size=32 \
    --validation_batch_size=-1 \
    --flip_left_right True \
    --random_scale=30 \
    --random_brightness=30 \
    --eval_step_interval=100 \
    --how_many_training_steps= 100000 \
    --architecture mobilenet_1.0_224
```

Is there a way to tweak the `image_dir` parameter to point to a locally stored dataset while running the training on EC2?

Answer (score 3):

Even if there was a way to train the model while pointing at a local directory, you'd still be in the situation where the data would have to transfer eventually. Have you considered uploading your datasets to an S3 bucket, and then copying from the bucket to your EC2 instance?

You'd still need the initial upload then, but you wouldn't have to reupload each time you started a new EC2 instance for a new training session, and the copy from the bucket to your instance will be much faster then copying from your local machine to the instance.